# How to Displaying an image with path stored in Database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, imageview

I have stored images path in database and images in project folder. Now i am trying to view all IMAGES with their PRODUCTS in my HTML template. I have written the following code and its given me an empty images box in the output and when i open that image box in the new tab, it opens the following URL.

```
 http://localhost/cms/1
```

Kindly tell me the way of referring images in 'img src ' tag.

[image]

```
include 'connect.php';

$image_query = "select * from product_images";
$image_query_run = mysql_query($image_query);
$image_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($image_query_run);


if (!$query=mysql_query ("select product_id,name from products")) {
    echo mysql_error();

} else {
    while ($query_array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '</br><pre>';

        $product_id = $query_array['product_id'];

        echo "<a href='single_product.php?product_id=$product_id' >";
        print_r ($query_array['name']);
        echo "</a>";

        echo "&lt;img src=". $image_query_fetch
        ['images'] ." alt=\"\" /&gt;";

        echo '</pre>';
    }
}

} else {
    echo "You need to Log in to visit this Page";

}
```

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated function as of php 5.5.0, use mysqli_ or PDO .**REF:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your local image path before source

**example**

```
echo "<img src='http://localhost/cms/1/". $image_query_fetch['images'] .'" alt=\"\" />";
```

**Use PHP **

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Comment: I would recommend relative URLs.

Comment: And do not use localhost if you plan to publish your HTML.

Comment: What are relative URLs? How can i use them here?

Comment: if u want to get dynamically that time u want to get base url........u can use pure php for that

Comment: Refer this link  http://www.cleverlogic.net/tutorials/how-dynamically-get-your-sites-main-or-base-url

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML base tag to set a base URL that relative URLs will be resolved from.
See -> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: IE. Then you just use <img src="upload/Tulips.jps">