# Displaying photos from url stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, base-url

This is my database:
[image]

I'm trying to display the image like this

```
  <?php
$displaymyavatar="SELECT * FROM avatars INNER JOIN users ON avatars.users_id=users.id WHERE username='$login_session'";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($db,$displaymyavatar);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){?>
              <img class="avatar" src='<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . $row['image_file'];?>' alt="">
 <?php };?>
```

I thought I found a solution [here](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875560/how-to-displaying-an-image-with-path-stored-in-database) but the image is not displaying. The image is uploaded in the folder "uploads"

Comment: You forgot to use `echo` within `while`

Comment: inspect your html code & check for img src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works:**

```
     <?php
$displaymyavatar="SELECT * FROM avatars INNER JOIN users ON avatars.users_id=users.id WHERE username='marydoe'";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($db,$displaymyavatar);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){?>
              <img class="avatar" src="core/<?php echo $row['image_file'] ?>" />
 <?php };?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would a relative link work for you? If so, you should be able to use the following code snippet.

```
<?php
   $displaymyavatar="SELECT * FROM avatars INNER JOIN users ON avatars.users_id=users.id WHERE username='$login_session'";
   $result_set=mysqli_query($db,$displaymyavatar);
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){ ?>
       <img class="avatar" src="./<?php echo $row['image_file']; ?>" alt="">
<?php };?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query you are using is returning data? It might be empty.

Comment: Yes. I tried it in Phpmyadmin. It returns one row as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop

```
<?php foreach ($result_set as $key => $r): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $r['image_file'] ?>" />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: For some reason your answer is the closest to giving a result. The image appears but as broken link...

Comment: inspect element and check the url and modify the source url.

Comment: Try putting this `<img src="./<?php echo $r['image_file'] ?>" />`

Comment: @Fried_Chicken: I did. But same.

Comment: Try this `<img src="/<?php echo $r['image_file'] ?>" />`